# breadcrumbs Sharepoint 365

Tags: office-365, breadcrumb

Very basic and beginner users of SharePoint 365 but would like to use/setup breadcrumbs before we move to far forward. What is the easiest way to make this happen please? we only have deisgner access

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint 2013 does not use breadcrumb like 2010 but you can enable it both for seattle and oslo  master page.

So if you  edit Seattle master page in advanced mode you will find following code

```
<div class="ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox" style="display:none;">
```

- So first Remove display:none
- Two lines bellow change the visible attribute of the SharePoint:PopoutMenu to true.

To enable the breadcrumb in Oslo you need to copy these lines of code from the Seattle master page into your copy of the Oslo master page.

http://academy.bindtuning.com/lets-bring-the-breadcrumb-back-to-sharepoint-2013/
http://www.wombit.se/2013/11/28/sharepoint-365-breadcrumb-oslo/

Answer (score 0):

By default SharePoint 2013 doesn’t have a breadcrumb (like the 2010 version used to have).  it’s just hidden in the Seattle master page.
In order to get it back, you have to edit the master page.

Follow the instruction from this post and get it back.http://academy.bindtuning.com/lets-bring-the-breadcrumb-back-to-sharepoint-2013/