# Trouble adding Breadcrumb settings to Master Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-365

I need to add the 'Breadcrumb' file path into our new Sharepoint Online.
I am **totally** inexperienced with configuring Sharepoint. I found a piece of JavaScript code from [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Folder-661709eb)

I've added it to the Master Page gallery, my difficulty is finding the Master Page (which I'm assuming is different to the gallery)

After lots of Googling I found a suggestion to go to Home>Site Settings>Look and Feel>Master Page

Unfortunately it isn't there. So my only solution is to go to each sub site and add the JS function to each List View Web Part manually which is going to be very long winded and time consuming.

Comment: which breadcrumb you want ?

Comment: The one in the link. It's essentially a Folder Path. Out of the box, SharePoint does not give you a Folder Path if you use it as a Document Store.

I'm very aware of the flaws in this system, but it's what I've been asked to do.

Answer (score 0):

Goto: **Site Settings -> Web Designer Galleries -> Master Page & Page Layouts** -> Select the master page where you want to add breadcrumb -> Download it and perform the [following changes](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132369/breadcrumbs-sharepoint-365), upload again.

Your changes should look like this:

```
    <div class="ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox" >
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaBreadcrumbDropdown" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:PopoutMenu
        Visible="true"
        runat="server"
        ID="GlobalBreadCrumbNavPopout"
        IconUrl="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=31"
        IconAlt="<%$Resources:wss,master_breadcrumbIconAlt%>"
        ThemeKey="v15breadcrumb"
        IconOffsetX="215"
        IconOffsetY="120"
        IconWidth="16"
        IconHeight="16"
        AnchorCss="ms-breadcrumb-anchor"
        AnchorOpenCss="ms-breadcrumb-anchor-open"
        MenuCss="ms-breadcrumb-menu ms-noList">
        <div class="ms-breadcrumb-top">
            <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="ms-breadcrumb-header" Text="<%$Resources:wss,master_breadcrumbHeader%>" />
        </div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:ListSiteMapPath
                runat="server"
                SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPContentMapProvider"
                RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false"
                PathSeparator=""
                CssClass="ms-breadcrumb"
                NodeStyle-CssClass="ms-breadcrumbNode"
                CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="ms-breadcrumbCurrentNode"
                RootNodeStyle-CssClass="ms-breadcrumbRootNode"
                NodeImageOffsetX="217"
                NodeImageOffsetY="210"
                NodeImageWidth="16"
                NodeImageHeight="16"
                NodeImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=31"
                RTLNodeImageOffsetX="199"
                RTLNodeImageOffsetY="210"
                RTLNodeImageWidth="16"
                RTLNodeImageHeight="16"
                RTLNodeImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=31"
                HideInteriorRootNodes="true"
                SkipLinkText="" />
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </SharePoint:PopoutMenu>
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
</div>
```

Words of wisdom: Avoid customizing master pages even though it is still supportive because Microsoft continuously release service updates so of them targeting Master pages (UI), leaving your copy of custom master page deprived of new service updates.

[image]